# Cant see Busy Indicator Control in SL 4 Toolkit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have installed VS2010 and then i installed the Silverlight 4 Toolkit, but i am unable to find the Busy Indicator control in the Toolbox.

Any solutions ??

thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

If you expand All Silverlight Controls --> Right click --> Sort Items alphabetically --> Are you sure its not there? If not, right click, "Choose Items" and search for BusyIndicator, it should definitely show up...

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I did search as you said but nothing shows up!!